# Getting HTTP Status 401 - type Status report message description This request requires HTTP authentication in Firefox 62, But working in FF 61.0.2

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using a Headless firefox browser to automate. below is my code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","drivers/geckodriver.exe");
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE,"true");
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE,"logs.txt");
    FirefoxBinary firefoxbinary = new FirefoxBinary();  
    firefoxbinary.addCommandLineOptions("-headless");
    FirefoxOptions firefoxoptions = new FirefoxOptions();
    firefoxoptions.setBinary(firefoxbinary);
    firefoxoptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxoptions);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The above code worked fine in FF 61.0.2. it will never ask the authentication pop up. But after updating my FF to 62.0 , it asking for authentication and fails. below is the screenshot
[Screenshot of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP9gl.png)

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace